# Spring Security Method Level Security Annotations NOT working

Tags: spring, struts2, annotations, spring-security

I am making a simple web application using Struts 2 + Spring Security 3. And I want to use Pre-Post Annotations for Method Level Security.

But the Annotations are not working.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>MyCustomSpringSecurity</display-name>

  <context-param>
<param-name>contextConfiguration</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

  <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="firstPage" class="code.action.MyAction" method="showPage">
        <result name="success">/firstPage.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" >
    </global-method-security>

    <beans:bean id="myAction" class="code.action.MyAction">
        <intercept-methods>
            <protect access="ROLE_ADMIN" method="showPage"/>
        </intercept-methods>
    </beans:bean>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/firstPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Finally This is MyAction.java

```
package code.action;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;

public class MyAction {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String showPage(){
        System.out.println("in showPage");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

You can clearly see that I am assigning role to user is ROLE_USER but I want it to be ROLE_ADMIN when accessing that method, so logically there should be error of 403 Access Denied when running this code. But it is able to access that method and shows next page.

So I think the annotations are not working.

Any body knows whats going on ?

Comment: Please do one test. Create a new Class SecuredAction and put the method with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation in this class. Then Inject that bean in MyAction, and invoke it from the showPage method.

Comment: I tried as you said. I created a new Class SecuredAction and put my @PreAuthorize annotation in that class and then created object of SecuredAction and called its method from MyAction : showPage() but still not working. or Should I try injecting object of SecuredAction using Spring Dependency Injection but I think it will be one and the same thing.

Comment: Yes you MUST use injection. -- I already mentioned it in my comment ("Then Inject that bean in MyAction"). -- The reason is that Spring AOP does only work for Spring Beans, not for normal instances.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. The only thing I was missing was Injecting beans. Now I used Spring Depenedency Injection and it is working fine. There was no need to create new SecuredAction.

Comment: can you please help me with my this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208501/struts-2-spring-spring-security-haspermission-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot directly use Spring annotations like this.

There is another plugin [Struts 2 - Spring Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-spring-plugin) for the same purpose. You can download the jar file from the link and include it in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the latest _working_ link as the older link has been removed.

Answer (score 4):

In order for Spring annotations to be meaningful in a Struts 2 action you must use the [Struts 2 Spring Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html). This will use Spring to instantiate Struts 2 objects, allowing annotation processing, injection, etc.

Comment: Thanks. This was what I was missing to get Spring DI working.

Comment: can you help me out with my this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208501/struts-2-spring-spring-security-haspermission-not-working