# Spring + Spring Security + hasPermission Not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring Security 3 with Struts 2 and Spring DI. I put hasRole() annotation in my code and it is working fine but hasPermission() annotation is not working. I have made expression handler, custom permission evaluator etc.

Here is the code

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans> 
 <import resource="mySecurity.xml"/>
<bean id="myAction" name="myAction" class="code.action.MyAction" autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean id="permission" name="permission" class="code.permission.Permission" autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean id="myEntity" name="myEntity" class="code.entities.MyEntity" autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" 
    name="expressionHandler" autowire="byName">
</bean>
<bean class="code.permission.MyCustomPermissionEvaluator" id="customPermissionEvaluator" name="customPermissionEvaluator" autowire="byName" />
</beans>
```

Here is my acl-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a simple map containing all our roles -->
    <util:map id="permissionsMap">
         <entry key="ROLE_USER" value-ref="user"/>
     </util:map>

 <!-- Declare permissions for Admin
  Contains a map of objects and their associated allowed actions -->
 <bean id="user" class="code.permission.Permission" >
  <property name="objects">
   <map>
    <entry key="code.entities.MyEntity">
     <list>
      <value>READ</value>
     </list>
    </entry>
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

this is mySecurity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- To enable Method Security Expressions and custom PermissionEvaluator
   we need to add the following -->
         <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
                <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
         </global-method-security>

 <!-- To use hasPermission() expressions, we have to configure a PermissionEvaluator -->
 <!-- See 15.3.2 Built-In Expression
   @http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-permission-evaluator -->
        <beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" name="expressionHandler" autowire="byName">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator" />
        <beans:property name = "roleHierarchy" ref="roleHierarchy"/>
     </beans:bean>

 <!-- Declare a custom PermissionEvaluator interface -->
 <beans:bean class="code.permission.MyCustomPermissionEvaluator" id="customPermissionEvaluator" name="customPermissionEvaluator" autowire="byName" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/firstPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchyImpl.html -->
    <beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"  class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl" name="roleHierarchy" autowire="byName">
      <beans:property name="hierarchy">
         <beans:value>
             ROLE_USER
         </beans:value>
     </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
 </beans:beans>
```

This is my Permission.java
    package code.permission;

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Contains a map of objects and their associated allowed actions
 */
public class Permission {

 /**
  *  A Map containing a list of objects and their corresponding actions
  *  <p>
  *  String: key name of the object
  *  List<String>: a list of permissions
  */
  private Map<String, List<String>> objects;

 public Map<String, List<String>> getObjects() {
  return objects;
 }
 public void setObjects(Map<String, List<String>> objects) {
  this.objects = objects;
 }

}
```

This is myCustomPermissionEvaluator.java

```
package code.permission;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class MyCustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

  @Resource(name="permissionsMap")
   private Map permissionsMap;

 @Resource(name="roleHierarchy")
 private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy;

 public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
   Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
     System.out.println("First hasPermission");

  String role = getRole(authentication);

  return hasPermission(role, permission, targetDomainObject);
 }

 /**
  * Another hasPermission signature. We will not implement this.
  */
 public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
    Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {

  return false;
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves the user's highest role
  */
 private String getRole(Authentication authentication) {
  String highestRole = null;

  try {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> auths = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>)   roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities());
   for (GrantedAuthority auth: auths) {
    highestRole = auth.getAuthority();
    break;
   }

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

  return highestRole;
 }

 private Boolean hasPermission(String role, Object permission, Object domain) {
     System.out.println("Second hasPermission");
  if ( permissionsMap.containsKey(role) ) {
        Permission userPermission = (Permission) permissionsMap.get(role);

  if ( userPermission.getObjects().containsKey(domain.getClass().getName())){

    for (String action: userPermission.getObjects().get(domain.getClass().getName()) ) {
      if (action.equals(permission)) {

       return true;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  return false;
 }
}
```

this is MyAction.java

```
package code.action;

import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import code.entities.MyEntity;

public class MyAction {
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String showPage(){
        System.out.println("in MyAction : showPage");
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        if(isAccessible(entity))
            return "success";
        else
            return "input";
    }
     @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#entity,'WRITE')")
    public boolean isAccessible(MyEntity entity){
        System.out.println("in MyAction : isAccessible");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any expert here to tell me why this hasPermission() not working ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work, because Spring AOP can only incercept calls between beans, but not if you invoke a method of the same bean.

So either you move the `isAccessible` Method to an other bean, or use use AspectJ instead of Spring Proxy AOP.

An other idea would be using the permission evaluation directly, instead of having the annotated method. (But I do not know exactly how this can be done.)

Comment: thanks again ! what i did, i made a service class and put my method isAccessible() in that class. BUT it gives me error "Denying user user permission 'READ' on object code.entities.MyEntity@da5318", but I have given READ permission in xml file and also it is not coming in hasPermission() method of MyCustomPermissionEvaluator.

Comment: i want to check permissions from database. For that i will write my own code in service layer. So if control will come in hasPermission() method then from here I will call my service methods to check permissions. But it is not coming to hasPermission(). It is showing Warning before that.

Comment: Well ! I got it my self. I just removed bean of MyCustomPermissionEvaluator from applicationContext.xml and it started working. Thanks a log For YOUR HELP AND SUPPORT.

Comment: Hello ! I need some more help from you. Everything is working fine now. But I want to customize page to be shown on failure of hasPermission. Presently it shows some HTTP 500 - error page with exception org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied. I want to show here a customized page. I have already made a AccessDecisionHandler that works for 404 Access Denied but not here.

Comment: @Gurparsad Singh - This is a nice new question. (I am very busy to day, so write this as a new question, and hopefully somebody else has more time.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ralph for you Help. I already put a new question and somehow I am able to show login page using <exception-mapping exception="org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException" 
result="login" /> in struts.xml. New question is <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225805/custom-error-page-spring-security-3-haspermission">here.</a>