# custom error Page + spring security 3 + hasPermission

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security

how to show a custom error page when user fails to see a page (when do not have specific permission) after getting HTTP 500 -

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Exception from custom hasPermission() method.

You can check my previous question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208501/struts-2-spring-spring-security-haspermission-not-working)  to see my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your struts2 config file you can configure global exceptions like

```
<global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException" result="securityerror" />
     <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error" />
   </global-exception-mappings>

  <global-results>
        <result name="securityerror">/securityerror.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
   </global-results>
```

that will work for application level if you find fine grained exception handling thing you can define it for action level itself

```
<action name="actionspecificexception" class="org.apache.struts.register.action.Register" method="throwSecurityException">
     <exception-mapping exception="org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException" 
          result="login" />
      <result>/register.jsp</result>
      <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
   </action>
```

So it depends upon you choice how you want to configure it.for details refer.

[Exception handling in Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/exception-handling.html)

My suggestion is not to throw every exception as a raw one better create your own exception wrappers and wrap such exceptions in them it will help you to organize your code in better way

Hope this will help you.